# Integrate react-fontawesome on nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jss

I use **nextjs** with **JSS** to styling my components. I want to be able to add **react-fontawesome** inside my project but I encoutered a problem to integrate the library functionnality.

I tried differents way to implement it but any of them work. Here a codesandbox with my code - https://codesandbox.io/s/v6pyxp00w0

The preview render of codesandbox seems break but all the code are on here. 
When I run my code, this error message is display on client and server consoles:

`Could not find icon { prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'facebook' }`

Do you think I should call the library function inside my *app.js* file instead of my *document.js*? Have you an idea to fix my problem?
Thanks you very much!

Comment: Your codesandbox does not exist anymore, but I think you forgot to properly include the icon. Did you fix the issue? I used react-fontawesome in my NextJS project and it works out of the box, but I'm fighting with the missing styles during server side rendering.